# How does Augmentation work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following component

```
const MyComp = () => <div>abc</div>;
```

which will be rendered into

```
<div>abc</div>
```

And I want `MyComp` component's element type to be dynamic, An example if the Component is used as `<MyComp as='a' />` then the component should be rendered into `<a>abc</a>`. I have seen this being used in Sementic UI and they call this pattern element augmentation. I did a search on this but could not find anything useful. How to achieve this?

Comment: I think you'd pass the component you want rendered as a prop and simply put it in the render method of the component it is passed to. Not sure if that is what you are talking about, but what I could think of

Comment: @brandNew I want to know how they have implemented the feature they are talking under section  `Augmentation`  in this page https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction#augmentation :)

Comment: Are you look for <MyComp as='div' /> to render <div>div</div>, <a>div</a>, or <div>a</div>?

Comment: @G Cadogan I am sorry that there was a typo in ky question. Corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a tag name in JSX starts with an upper case letter, then this will be treated as an identifier. This identifier is normally a user-defined react component, but can also be a string and will render a 'leaf' react component, i.e. a DOM node.

So to get the behaviour that you want:

```
const MyComp = ({ as: Component = 'div' }) => <Component>abc</Component>;
```

Comment: Good answer, indeed the combination of  [ES6 objects destructuring with assignment](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingDeepMatching) and tag names starting with an uppercase being treated as identifiers makes this possible.

Answer (score 3):

The terminology you are looking for is **rendering dynamic components**

You can do it something on the lines of

```
    render() {
    const ComponentToRender = this.props.as;
    return (
        <a><ComponentToRender /></a>
    )
}
```

where your prop gets value inside a constant which can then be rendered as a react component

Comment: Mentioned you in my answer, yours is a more accurate definition of the design pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the gesture Alexandre!!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: aseem-upadhyay is correct, the exact terminogy is "dynamic component" which is a more accurate way of defining this concept, although dynamically rendered components are rendered by HOCs**

"rendering as" is an oversimplification of the process to help with the mental representation. 
In reality, you have an higher order component that will render another one(the "as" one), with extra props passed to it.

So, it's return value will essentially be the "as" element.

Have a look at the [Button](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/elements/Button/Button.js#L31) component source code, for example.

Comment: Could you please explain this using a code in your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prop `as` as your component:

**Example**

```
function App(props) {
  const As = props.as;
  return <As> Test </As>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App as="div" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```